# How to "extend" javascript "class" and add new stuff?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is make a Projectile class, and then make a BasicShot class that "extends" Projectile in a way like you can in Java.

I want to set the vars the parent has to the parent class, and any new vars get set in the child class.

```
var Projectile = function(x, y){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
}

Projectile.prototype.update(){
     console.log("should not be called");
}

Projectile.prototype.checkIfWallHit(){
     console.log("should be called");
}
```

and then the child class.

```
var BasicShot = new function(x, y, left){
     this = new Projectile(x,y);
     this.left = left;
}

BasicShot.prototype.update(){
     console.log("should be called");
}
```

But when I try to do this it says "BasicShot not defined" when I try to make a BasicShot object.

So, how do I extend my Projectile class?

Comment: As the question is about JavaScript, not Java, I've removed the `java` tag.

Comment: Did you actually write it as `BasicShot.prototype.update(){` in your code? That's not proper JS syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic pattern, see comments:

```js
// === Projectile

// The constructor
function Projectile(x, y) {
    // Do things to initialize instances...
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Add some methods to its prototype
Projectile.prototype.update = function() {
    // This is a method on `Projectile`
    snippet.log("Projectile#update");
};
Projectile.prototype.checkIfWallHit = function(){
    snippet.log("Projectile#checkIfWallHit");
};

// ==== BasicShot

// The constructor
function BasicShot(x, y, left) {
    // Give Projectile a chance to do its thing
    Projectile.call(this, x, y);
    this.left = left;
}
// Hook it up to `Projectile`
BasicShot.prototype = Object.create(Projectile.prototype);
BasicShot.prototype.constructor = BasicShot; // JavaScript does this by default, so let's maintain it when replacing the object

// Add methods to its prototype
BasicShot.prototype.update = function() {
    snippet.log("BasicShot#update");
};

// === Usage
snippet.log("Using Projectile");
var p = new Projectile(1, 2);
p.update(); // Projectile#update
p.checkIfWallHit(); // Projectile#checkIfWallHit

snippet.log("Using BasicShot");
var c = new BasicShot(1, 2, 3);
c.update(); // BasicShot#update
p.checkIfWallHit(); // Projectile#checkIfWallHit
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

As of ES6, the next version of JavaScript, that gets a **lot** simpler:

```
// REQUIRES ES6!!
class Projectile {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    update() {
        snippet.log("Projectile#update");
    }
    checkIfWallHit() {
        snippet.log("Projectile#checkIfWallHit");
    }
};

class BasicShot extends Projectile {
    constructor(x, y, left) {
        super(x, y);
        this.left = left;
    }
    update() {
        snippet.log("BasicShot#update");
    }
}
```

It does the same thing as first example above under the covers, the new syntax is just syntactic sugar. But it's really good sugar.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. It took me a while to figure out why this code wasn't working when I applied it to my project. I was calling Projectile.call( x, y); and not Projectile.call(this, x, y);

Anyway, thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/0qkevb0q/2/

```
var factory = {};

factory.getProjectileObject = function(xarg, yarg){

    var Projectile = function(x, y){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
    }

    Projectile.prototype.update = function() {
         console.log("should not be called");
    }

    Projectile.prototype.checkIfWallHit = function() {
         console.log("should be called");

    }

    return new Projectile(xarg, yarg);
}

factory.getBasicshotObject = function(xarg, yarg, leftarg) {

    var BasicShot = function(left){
         this.left = left;
    }

    // Extending parents methods
    BasicShot.prototype = factory.getProjectileObject(xarg, yarg);
    BasicShot.prototype.constructor = BasicShot;

    BasicShot.prototype.update = function(){
         console.log("should be called");
    }

    return new BasicShot(leftarg);
}

i = factory.getBasicshotObject(12,34, 23);
console.log(i);
```

Comment: `BasicShot.prototype = new Projectile(x,y)` is an anti-pattern. The *reason* it's an anti-pattern is actually obvious from your code: What values would you use for `x` and `y` at the point you're defining a `BasicShot` constructor?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i wanted to use factory pattern, i was not able to complete the whole code. heres jsfiddle of that code http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/0qkevb0q/1/ can you take a look at this and give your feedback please, that would really help me. thanx in advance

Comment: I suggest you simply read my answer for the correct way to do this with constructor functions. The fiddle ends up creating a lot of extra things every time you want an object, which is unnecessary and convoluted. You're creating whole new constructor functions and whole new prototype objects **every time** you create an object.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to achieve such kind of inheritance is to use prototypical inheritance.

One general practice is to associate a global function to Object and using it to create derived objects. (since global is bad, again there are ways to circumvent this).

```
Object.prototype.begetObject = function () {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = this;
    return new F();
};

BasicShot= Projectile.begetObject();
```

you can override/extend functionality to this basicShot object in the same way you proposed in the question.

```
BasicShot.prototype.update = function (){
     console.log("should be called");
};
```

I highly recommend going through this nice article on prototypical inheritance which is definitely worth.
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: *"Best way to achieve such kind of inheritance is to use prototypical inheritance"* Well, yes, because in JavaScript, that's the only kind of inheritance there is. You're using prototypical inheritance whether you use constructor functions or builder functions.